# highlight words on page just like jQuery.highlight()?

Tags: php, jquery

I am currently using jQuery.highlight() to highlight given words on page and link them. But it took long if we have lots of words to check and highlight on a page.

I know how jQuery.highlight() functions, but can't think if we can implement the same functionality using PHP.

Is there anyway in php to highlight words and link them just like jQuery.highlight() doing? In addition to question, I want to mention that there can be static and dynamic contents on the page.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php : Replace all occurrences of the search string with the replacement string. `str_replace($search , '<span class="highlight">'.$search.'</span>', $string)`

Answer (score 1):

If you know what words need to be highlighted, just make a css class `higlight` and use as follows:`<span class='highlight'>My highlighted text</span>`.

As for the css, use for example

```
.highlight{
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

You can also use `str_replace` to replace certain words, like so:

```
str_replace( $word, '<span class="highlight">'.$word.'</span>', $mytext)
```

`$mytext` would obviously be the the whole text, and `$word` the word you wish to highlight. You could make an array of words that need to be highlighted and just do a `foreach()`.

Comment: as i said at the comment

Comment: Oh didn't see your comment yet, indeed!

Comment: It works on whatever content you put through the `str_replace()`

Comment: Just keep in mind the functionality of jQuery.highlight(). I have to search whole html page, actually. That's why I am asking. How can replace whole renard html page? That was my actual question.

Comment: If I am understanding this correctly, you are currently generating html-code with php, and the jQuery.highlight() just scans your document and inserts the `<span class='highlight'></span>`-tags. What you must do now is just before `echo`-ing out the html, run it though the `str_replace()`-function.

Comment: Your understanding is correct. If I am going to display the contents from database (dynamic contents), I can achieve this easily. But when there are static contents on the page (static html), am I able to highlight the words in those contents? 

*I am not using any CMS or framework.

Comment: Okay, forget about the dynamic contents. Here is an example.. Let say I have build an html page (test.php) with static html contents (not echo-ing through PHP). Can I any php function to highlight words in my html contents?

Comment: So you are including an html-file? You can say `$html = file_get_contents("myhtmlpage.html")` and then apply the function.